# Why am I getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +

Tags: python, syntax, types

When I run my script, I get a `TypeError`.
This is all of my code:

```
lawnCost = ("£15.50")
lengthLawn = float(input("Lengh of lawn: "))
widthLawn = float(input("Width of lawn: "))

totalArea = (lengthLawn) * (widthLawn)

print (("The total area of the lawn is ")+str(totalArea)+str("m²"))

totalCost = (totalArea) * float(15.50)

print ("The cost of lawn per m² is £15.50")
print ("The total cost for the lawn is ")+str(totalCost)
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

If anyone could help point me in the right direction that would be great, thank you.

Also if it helps I am running Python 3.3 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the last line, `str(totalCost)` needs to be *inside* the parenthesis for `print`:

```
print ("The total cost for the lawn is "+str(totalCost))
```

This is because `print` returns `None` in Python 3.x.  So, your code is actually trying to do this:

```
None+str(totalCost)
```

---

Also, if you want it, below is a version of your script that is a little cleaner and more efficient:

```
lawnCost = "£15.50"
lengthLawn = float(input("Lengh of lawn: "))
widthLawn = float(input("Width of lawn: "))

totalArea = lengthLawn * widthLawn

print("The total area of the lawn is {}m²".format(totalArea))

totalCost = totalArea * 15.50

print("The cost of lawn per m² is £15.50")
print("The total cost for the lawn is {}".format(totalCost))
```

Basically, I did three things:

1. Removed unnecessary parenthesis and the extra spaces after `print`.
2. Removed unecessary calls to `str` and `float`.
3. Incorporated the use of [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful and correct. Many thanks for the cleaner code, will be able to learn by comparing the two. Thanks.